# I have both pip and conda installed on Mac. What is the best way to manage python packages now?

Tags: pip, conda

I have pip installed.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pip --version
pip 19.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Then I installed anaconda2

Now, my default pip becomes the pip in anaconda2 folder

```
$ /Users/admin/anaconda2/bin/pip --version
pip 18.1 from /Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip 
(python 2.7)
```

Someone said, that after I installed conda, I should just use

```
conda install
```

Forget about

```
pip install
```

I don't know if it is true.

But now with both conda and pip installed. Specially conda makes python and  most python package using the ones conda installed as default, I do run into more problems when I install some packages. Such as after I do

```
pip install
```

some packages, the errors will tell me certain tools/scripts not available (but the missing tools/scripts are in conda folder)

My questions:

- How should I manage the python packages when I have both Conda and pip installed?
- When should I use "conda install", and when should I use "pip install"?
- I tried "conda install" sometimes, "conda install" seems slow. And after "conda install", my command line terminal, showed

  (base)Admin-iMac:~ admin$

  Every time I opened my command line terminal, the terminal is running conda's virtual environment.

  Something is wrong of these "conda install" that leads my terminal using conda virtual env as default now?
- If I use pip install, I have two pips, pip and the pip in conda folder to use, which one should I use? if use the pip under conda folder (which is default now)

  /Users/admin/anaconda2/bin/pip install ...

  The packages installed this way, will the package also show up in

  conda list

  Or will it show up in

  pip list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda is usually used to create fresh environments. After you activate a conda environment only software that was installed in that environment is used.

In a conda environment you usually use `conda install` to install stuff but you can do the same with `pip install`. See [Documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment) regarding `pip` in conda environments.

What you generally should not do, is to install everything globally.

You can find more information in the [Conda Documentation about environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: I did not install conda specifically. I downloaded Anaconda2, and then conda is installed globally after I just run the anaconda2 installer on iMac. You mean I should install Anaconda2 Navigator in virtual environment?

Comment: No, but you can remove it from your bashrc - than you have to run something like 'source anaconda/bin/activate' if you want to access programs installed with conda